# celeryev Queue in RabbitMQ Becomes Very Large

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I am using celery on rabbitmq. I have been sending thousands of messages to the queue and they are being processed successfully and everything is working just fine. However, the number of messages in several rabbitmq queues are growing quite large (hundreds of thousands of items in the queue). The queues are named `celeryev.[...]` (see screenshot below). Is this appropriate behavior? What is the purpose of these queues and shouldn't they be regularly purged? Is there a way to purge them more regularly, I think they are taking up quite a bit of disk space.

[image: screenshot of rabbitmq control]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_TTL`](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-event_queue_ttl) celery option (only working with amqp), that will set the message expiry time, after which it will be deleted from the queue.

Comment: This link is now a dead link. Do you have an updated one? Is it now https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-event_queue_ttl ?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else who is running into problems with a `celeryev` queue becoming very large and threatening the disk space on your rabbitmq server, beware the accepted answer! Here's my suggestion. Just issue this command on your rabbitmq instance:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy limit_celeryev_queues "^celeryev\." '{"max-length":1000000}' --apply-to queues
```

This will limit any queue beginning with "celeryev" to 1 Million entries. I did some experimenting with a stuck `flower` instance causing a runaway celeryev queue, and setting [CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_TTL](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-event-queue-ttl) / [CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-event-queue-expires) did **not** help control the queue size.

In my testing, I started a `flower` process, then SIGSTOP'ed it, and watched its celeryev queue start running away. Neither of these two settings helped at all. I confirmed SIGCONT'ing the `flower` process would bring the queue back to 0 rapidly. I am not certain why these two knobs didn't help, but it may have something to do with how RabbitMQ implements these two settings.

First, the [Per-Message TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) corresponding to `CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_TTL` only establishes an expiration time on each queue entry --  AIUI it will not automatically delete the message out of the queue to save space upon expiration. Second, the [Queue TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) corresponding to `CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES` says that it "... guarantees that the queue will be deleted, if unused for at least the expiration period". However, I  believe that their definition of "unused" may be too strict to kick in for e.g. an overburdened, stuck, or killed flower process.

EDIT: Unfortunately, one problem with this suggestion is that the `set_policy ... apply-to queues` will only impact **existing** queues, and flower can and will create **new** queues which may overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Celery use `celeryev` prefixed queues (and exchange) for [monitoring](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html), you can configure it as you want or disable at all (`celery control disable_events`).

Comment: Is there a way to reduce or limit event storage rather than turn it off altogether?

Comment: Have you tried --maxrate and --frequency arguments (or some other?) which may be placed in CELERYEV_OPTS, I guess

Comment: Were you able to make use of --maxrate or --frequency options? @pinepain

Answer (score 5):

You just have to set a config to your Celery.

If you want to avoid Celery from creating `celeryev.*` queues:

```
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False # Will not create celeryev.* queues
```

If you need these queues for monitoring purpose (CeleryFlower for instance), you may regularly purge them:

```
CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES = 60 # Will delete all celeryev. queues without consumers after 1 minute.
```

The solution came from here: https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/celery.html

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the queue size in RabbitMQ with **x-max-length** queue declaration argument

http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html