# What is the celeryev queue for?

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I'm running python celery with MongoDB as the broker since it stores the rest of my application's data. (This is an experimental setup for celery, so I know I am doing it wrong.) I have found that the celery messages collection contains 20 million documents which is just ridiculous. So I deleted any of the documents older than 7 days, but that still left me with more than a million documents in messages. Most of them have a queue like: `celeryev.35159580-6c35-40cd-b75b-66eb8333963d`. What is that queue used for and can they be safely deleted?

Comment: I found a rather old open ticket about this issue here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1047 but no solutions provided.

Comment: Supposedly this is caused by using celery flower, but I am not using that tool so no idea how 20 million celeryev queues were created in my DB: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/celery-users/celeryev|sort:date/celery-users/Xr7Nc2cjyIg/SctfBqq5VaUJ

Comment: [This answer says it's for monitoring](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17780124/500202), although "celeryev" doesn't appear in the text on the linked page.  [It is in a screenshot](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#celery-events-curses-monitor), though when I try to use it all that happens is a second "celeryev" appears